# How to prevent using library compiled for a different version

Tags: c++, dll

Is there any standard way to force users to use my dll library exactly in the same version used during compilation ?

Lets assume I have library in version 1.0 with a function:

```
extern "C" void A();
```

In version 1.1 I have added breaking change e.g.: another parameter to this function so I have:

```
extern "C" void A(int);
```

The exported name in dll is exactly the same but if the developer compile the product with version 1.1, then send it to the customer and the customer will update only the product (exe file) then everything will fail. And it may fail in random point at runtime (depending on when this changed function is executed).

Are there any standard ways to prevent loading the library in wrong version ? I'm mostly interested with solution for Windows dll files. (But if there are solutions specific to other platforms, please leave the comment)

The example above is simplified. Adding c++ mangling solves the particular problem above, but I'm looking for more general solution.

My idea is to add a static object in the library header file. This static object in constructor could execute method from the library and the method in name has encoded current version like: init_library_1_1(); So if the method is missing in dll then at very beginning user see that something is wrong. But the solution looks like a dirty workaround. And I have to take care that developer include this file.

Is there any better solution for such problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I was able to do:

In your .dll file add exported function:

```
extern "C"
{
    DLL_FUNCTION void library_dll_required_in_version_10_0_1() {}
}
```

In public header add:

```
namespace library_impl{

    extern "C"{
        DLL_FUNCTION void library_dll_required_in_version_10_0_1();
    }

    class VersionProtection{
    public:
        VersionProtection() {
            library_dll_required_in_version_10_0_1();
        }
    };
    static VersionProtection aversion_protection_verifier;
}
```

Finally If user try to use application with wrong version of the dll file then he receive nice error message at program startup:

> The procedure entry point library_dll_required_in_version_10_0_1
>   could not be located in the dynamic link library

You need to update the function version number after each breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard answer but many compiler/linker pairs have non-standard features to perform these kinds of tests.

Visual C++ for example has "#pragma detect_mismatch" that places a record in the output object file and then when the link is performed the records are tested and if they don't match an error is reported. I don't believe this would do any good if the DLL were loaded dynamically at run-time rather than statically during the load. I believe gcc/clang have something similar but don't know the details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately If I understand it correctly, it may help only when linking static library. I'm looking for the solution in runtime. When the user has version mismatch between library and application which use this library.